# Can you obtain the user id from the Auth Logout event?

Tags: laravel

I am using Listeners in a Laravel 5.8 application to log User actions.

I would like to create a log record for when the User Logs in and Out.

My Login functionality is working fine: i can retrieve the user id via `auth()->id()`.

I am having problems identifying the logged out user id in the Logout functionality.

I have my subscriber:

```
        $events->listen(
            'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventSubscriber@handleUserLogout'
        );
```

and i am trying to find the user id of the logged out user...

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Log;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use App\User;

class UserEventSubscriber
{    
public function handleUserLogout($event) {
        return $this->recordCandActivity(array(auth()->id(), 'logged out', 'User logged Out', 'Logout', 'No link'));
    }
```

but `auth()->id()` is (of course) rendered empty post logout.

Does anyone know a way of retrieving the just logged out user id from the Auth Logout event?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Logout.php) file, you could see that it has two properties: `user` and `guard`.

Those properties are accessible through the `$event` parameter in your listener.

```php
public function handleUserLogout($event) {
    return $this->recordCandActivity($event->user->id, 'logged out', 'User logged Out', 'Logout', 'No link'));
}
```

Comment: Azeos, thanks for the reply. Yes, i'd already tried that and it was recording a non-object. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-57-user-id-in-logout-event

Comment: Just tried that again... "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: Just tried in 6.0 and it's working. Do a `dd($event)` to see what you are getting.

Comment: Logout {#634 ▼
  +guard: "web"
  +user: User {#639 ▼
    #fillable: array:3 [▼
      0 => "name"
      1 => "email"
      2 => "password"
    ]
    #hidden: array:2 [▼
      0 => "password"
      1 => "remember_token"
    ]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: "users"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:10 [▼
      "id" => 1

Comment: So there DOES appear to be a User and a valid attribute id within the event...??

Comment: @Greenie try $event->user['id']

Comment: @azeós Now working?! Unsure why. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know what could have happened... I'm glad it worked.